# ORACLE PL/SQL: selecting multiple distinct rows and limiting amount of rows

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Currently i have the table

```
CREATE TABLE itemInventory
(
itemSerial Number(4),
typeOfItemID Number(4) [this is a foreign key]
);

INSERT INTO partInventory VALUES (200, 1);
INSERT INTO partInventory VALUES (300, 2);
INSERT INTO partInventory VALUES (400, 1);
```

this is the select statement i currently have but its returning me too many values [-00913]

`SELECT DISTINCT typeOfItemID BULK COLLECT INTO clonetbl FROM ItemInventory GROUP BY typeOfItemID;`

how do i limit the amount of rows i'm receiving to only 1 per typeofitem ID? so if i run a query it will only return the 200, 1 and 300, 2

EDIT: in my declare I have

```
TYPE cloned IS TABLE OF itemInventory%ROWTYPE;
clonetbl cloned;
```

Comment: First, what is `clonetbl`?  If you're getting an ORA-00913 error, that implies that the definition of `clonetbl` doesn't match the select list of your query.  It has nothing to do with the number of rows that are returned.  Second, how do you know which row you want if there are two with the same `typeOfItemID`?  Do you want the smallest `itemSerial`?  In your real table, are there other columns that you want returned as well?  Or is it just the two?

Comment: `TYPE cloned IS TABLE OF itemInventory%ROWTYPE;`
`clonetbl cloned;`

It doesn't matter if its the min/max value of the item serial as long as it does not get more than 1 of the typeOfItemID

I just want the 2 to be returned

Comment: Justin Cave's comment was spot on.  Your `clonetbl` is expecting both columns `itemSerial` and `typeOfItemID`.  That's what `itemInventory%rowtype` does.  But you are only selecting `typeOfItemID`.  The columns don't match.

Comment: ah, so I should make it `DISTINCT ItemSerial, typeOfItemID BULK ..` ?

Comment: ... or change the definition of your `cloned` type.  Whatever makes sense in your case.

Answer (score 0):

As Justin Cave pointed out in the comments, your error is due to a mismatch between your `cloned` type and your `select` list.

Your `cloned` type expects a ***full*** row with all the columns (`itemSerial` and `typeOfItemID` columns). That's what `itemInventory%ROWTYPE` means.

But your `select` only provides the `typeOfItemID` column, causing your error.

In your case, to fix your problem, you should probably just consider modifying the definition of `cloned` to this:

```
TYPE cloned IS TABLE OF itemInventory.typeOfItemID%TYPE;
```